# Python seaborn error with scatterplot and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot T-SNE reduced vectors with Seaborn. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=40, n_iter=300)
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(final_data)

df_subset = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['tsne-2d-one', 'tsne-2d-two']) 
df_subset['tsne-2d-one'] = tsne_results[:,0]
df_subset['tsne-2d-two'] = tsne_results[:,1]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))

sns.scatterplot(
    x="tsne-2d-one", y="tsne-2d-two",
    hue="y",
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
    data=df_subset,
    legend="full")
```

As you can see from above code, it seems that the scatterplot from seaborn lib requires a Panda.DataFrame input, so basically I am initializing it empty this way

```
df_subset = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['tsne-2d-one', 'tsne-2d-two'])
```

Then, I basically assign columns of this dataframe to each TSNE dimension

```
df_subset['tsne-2d-one'] = tsne_results[:,0]
df_subset['tsne-2d-two'] = tsne_results[:,1]
```

I can print these values without any problem.

However, when I run the code, here is what I get:

```
File "balance-training.py", line 59, in <module>
    legend="full")
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py", line 1335, in scatterplot
    alpha=alpha, x_jitter=x_jitter, y_jitter=y_jitter, legend=legend,
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py", line 852, in __init__
    x, y, hue, size, style, units, data
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py", line 142, in establish_variables
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'y'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

There is no column `y`, so you can remove `hue="y"`:

```
sns.scatterplot(
    x="tsne-2d-one", y="tsne-2d-two",
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
    data=df_subset,
    legend="full")
```

I think here is possible pass both vectors to `x` and `y` parameters and omit `data` parameter:

```
sns.scatterplot(
    x=tsne_results[:,0], y=tsne_results[:,1]
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
    legend="full")
```

**Sample**:

```
tsne_results = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,1]])
print (tsne_results)
[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [7 1]]

sns.scatterplot(
    x=tsne_results[:,0], y=tsne_results[:,1],
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 10),
    legend="full")
```

[image: g]

Comment: Rookie mistake :-(  Thank you